# how to add zip file on your site and download in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

While creating functionality to add zip file download in codeigniter, 
the Zip file downloads but is empty

```
public function zip()
{
    $this->load->library('zip');
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $path = './View/items/reveal';

    $files = get_filenames($path);
    foreach($files as $f)
    {
        $this->zip->read_file($path.$f, true);
    }

    $this->zip->download('test.zip');

}
```

Comment: Error = Archive is either in unknown format or damaged

Comment: Hopefully that was what you were asking. The previous version was quite confusing

Comment: Using latest version sir